# I am trying to create a query that by store list the maximum number of store visits made by a customer

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to link item_scan_fact, store_dimension and member_dimension. This is what I have. I cannot understand why it is not working:

```
DATABASE UA_SAMSCLUB_STAR;
select 
store_key, member_key, max(visitnum)
from 
item_scan_fact
where hello, store_key, member_key IN 
(select item_scan_fact.store_key, item_scan_fact.member_key, Count (*) as visitnum
from 
item_scan_fact
group by 
store_key, member_key)
group by 
store_key, member_key;
```

Comment: Don't know if it's because in your where clause you are asking hello, store_key, member key, but in your subquery you only ask for two items...

Comment: that was a typing mistake in the question. In my code I have instead of hello I have visitnum everywhere

Comment: `where hello, store_key, member_key IN 
(select item_scan_fact.store_key, item_scan_fact.member_key, Count (*) as visitnum` doesn't add up. Is this still the same typo. If so, please fix it. Please also include sample data for these tables and desired results. As-is this is just a SQL statement that may or may not be write. It's syntactically correct... fwiw.

Comment: *not working* is not an actual error message. Based on your confusing description you might want `select item_scan_fact.store_key, item_scan_fact.member_key, Count (*) as visitnum
from 
item_scan_fact
group by 
store_key, member_key QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY store_key ORDER BY visitnum DESC) = 1`